# How to set height for Coordinator Layout's childs in percentage?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I want to design a layout composed from: a toolbar at the top of the layout (which should take 20% of the screen), then, vertically,underneath, a ViewPager (which should take 60% of the screen) and then, still vertically underneath, a BottomSheet (which should take 20% of the screen when it is collapsed and to take 100% of the screen when it is expanded).
 Now I have declared the bottomsheet like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/BSSECONDTOOLBAR"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="???"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#f44242" />
```

Since this should be a direct child of a `CoordinatorLayout` I cannot use the `layout_weight` attribute.
 My question is how do I set the `BottomSheet` height in percentage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things to address in your question. The first is how to make the bottom sheet fill the parent when it is expanded.

This is quite simple: set `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Then we have to address setting the peek height of the bottom sheet to be 20% of the parent. This is not possible to do in XML because `CoordinatorLayout` doesn't support weights or percentages. Therefore, we have to set it in Java. You can add this code to your `onCreate()` method:

```
// assume `coordinator` is your CoordinatorLayout

coordinator.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        coordinator.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        int twentyPercent = (coordinator.getHeight() / 5);

        // make the toolbar 20% of the screen
        View toolbar = findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar_id);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams toolbarParams = toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        toolbarParams.height = twentyPercent;
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarParams);

        // make the viewpager the rest of the screen (60%)
        View pager = findViewById(R.id.your_viewpager_id);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams pagerParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) pager.getLayoutParams();
        pagerParams.topMargin = twentyPercent;
        pagerParams.height = (coordinator.getHeight() - (twentyPercent * 2));
        pager.setLayoutParams(pagerParams);

        // make the bottomsheet 20% of the screen
        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.BSSECONDTOOLBAR);
        BottomSheetBehavior<View> behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setPeekHeight(twentyPercent);
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all I am sorry for replying that late. Secondly, I am using C# and Xamarin but there is no problem.So, acording to what you are saying my layout  sketch should look like this: 
`<CoordinatorLayout> 
  <LinearLayout>
    <Toolbar>
    <ViewPager>
  </LinearLayout>
    <BottomSheet>
  </CoordinatorLayout>`
<Toolbar> and <ViewPager> are placed inside a <LinearLayout> so I can set their precentage by using layout_weight atribute. <br> After I declare the layout file in this way I should use your code to make the BottomSheet to fill 20% of the screen, right?

Comment: I think just `<CoordinatorLayout><Toolbar/><ViewPager/><BottomSheet/></CoordinatorLayout>`. No need for a LinearLayout anywhere.

Comment: Ok, but If I am not using a LinearLayout as a parent for Toolbar and ViewPager how can I set their height to be 20% and 60% of the screen?

Comment: @RaducuMihai see my updated answer. It's sort of a bummer that you have to do all this manual positioning of views, but `CoordinatorLayout` simply doesn't support this stuff out of the box so you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I understand that. I had so many attempts in order to get this done, I think I've already tryied to do it using your method, maybe I've done something wrong. I will try your code and let you know if it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is too late but this answer might help someone...

I achieved the half screen layout through below code.

```
BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet).peekHeight =
        (Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels)/2
```

I wanted to cover the half screen of any size device, thus I divided with 2 you can cover your desired device screen size amount by above code through changing the divider.

put this code in activity where your bottom sheet will pop up. (in `onCreate` method)

in code, `bottom_sheet` is the id given to bottom sheet root layout.